# Adding same object to the hashtable without creating multiple copies

Tags: c++11

I want to add same object multiple times because object will have multiple keys to it, i.e.: BMW, M5, 2015. When I print the table, I don't want to see 3 results for 3 keys, I want to see only 1 result displayed. Correct way to do it is to have node object point to the data rather than copy it:

```
struct Node
{
    Car * car_;
    Node * next;
}
```

What would be the correct way to implement it? My guess was to add object to the table and then make each new node point to the added object:

```
void hashTable::insert(Car * car_)
{
    char key[200];
    char curr[100];
    car_->getKeywords(key);

    char * token;
    token = strtok(key, ",");

    Node * srcNode = new Node;
    Node->car = car_;
    Node->next = NULL;

    int index = calculateIndex(token);

    srcNode->next = table[index];
    table[index] = srcNode;
    size++;

    while (token != NULL)
    {
        int index = calculateIndex(token);

        Node * newNode = new Node();
        newNode->car = srcNode->car; //How to make this node point to scrNode?

        newNode->next = table[index];
        table[index] = newNode;
        size++;
        token = strtok(NULL, "?");
    }
}
```

So, how would I make newNode point to the srcNode? Is my approach even correct?

Comment: To clarify, do you want a hash table where some elements are objects and some are pointers to those objects? Like where "BMW" might hold a car, but "2015" and "M5" then point to the car object held by "BMW"?

Comment: Since you tagged c++, why don't you use the stl library?

Comment: You will need cross referencing data structure. A map str->objects, and a map object->(str set). Which you will have to update both upon every update.

Comment: @JaysonBoubin No, I want everything to be pointers.

Comment: @LiranFunaro It's for learning purposes.

Comment: `newNode->event` There's no member named `event` in `Node`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik thanks, edited.

Comment: Well, both `newNode` and `srcNode` do point to the same `Car` instance. Is that not what you wanted? What again seems to be the problem?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I'm trying to make display show only 1 output instead of 3(one for each keyword), and I though that using pointers would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: 
http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Hash_table/Simple_example
They have a great implementation of a simple hash table in C++. Your current implementation has some structural issues, and I think you could learn from this link. To augment the one from this list to turn it into a hash table where the values are pointers, simply change the hashentry value member to be a pointer to whichever type you choose.